# Convert daily stock data into two day stock data

Tags: python, pandas, stock, yfinance

I am trying to convert a pandas series of 1-day data into two-day data. The way that this is done is by starting from the bottom and then skipping every other row.

This is the code I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf


tick = yf.Ticker("COST")
data_day = tick.history(period="500d", interval="1d", auto_adjust=False)["Close"].round(decimals=2)
data_2day = data_day.iloc[1::2]
```

Here is some of the data that the program is outputting. You can ignore the dates as I only care about the values of the close prices, and not the dates.

[image]

If you look at the bottom,  you will see that the close is 561.35, which is correct as of the time of this writing (3/19/2022). But, if you count 12 closes up from the most recent one, you will see the value as 509.67. When I check my stockbroker, the actual value for that should be 506.56. This is not a data issue as this exact number is present when I print the normal data_day data frame, which leads me to believe that there is something wrong with my formula. Could someone please help me identify the error?

Just for reference, here is the normal data_day data frame which has the close prices for the COST stock in daily aggregation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just one minor mistake, instead of `data_day.iloc[1::2]`, you should put `data_day.iloc[0::2]` as the index in Python always start with 0.

```
data_day.iloc[0::2]

Out[22]: 
Date
2021-12-22    549.67
2021-12-27    563.47
2021-12-29    567.77
2021-12-31    567.70
2022-01-04    564.23
2022-01-06    549.80
2022-01-10    518.80
2022-01-12    525.80
2022-01-14    502.99
2022-01-19    490.16
2022-01-21    481.61
2022-01-25    477.32
2022-01-27    482.52
2022-01-31    505.13
2022-02-02    522.02
2022-02-04    519.77
2022-02-08    521.15
2022-02-10    518.48
2022-02-14    506.56
2022-02-16    512.40
2022-02-18    512.67
2022-02-23    495.26
2022-02-25    517.49
2022-03-01    522.93
2022-03-03    533.05
2022-03-07    528.52
2022-03-09    527.65
2022-03-11    527.42
2022-03-15    542.32
2022-03-17    552.79
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I actually tried to do that, but if you look at the last value, it is 552.79 when it should be 561.35. So either way I do it, I can't get the right data values.

Comment: In that case, this data will always be refreshed every day by yfinance, so the best you can do is to refresh it every day, or just use daily data, instead of 2d interval data